# Confusion with time complexity in "Find a pair with the given difference"

Tags: arrays, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I am trying to learn time complexity with algorithms. I found this problem interesting which says that: "Find the pairs with the given difference". I understand the problem and narrowed down to 2 methods which are:

```
1. Using Binary search (Time complexity: O(nLogn) in worst case)
2. Use hash (Time comlexity: O(n), Space complexity : O(n))
```

Please can someone explain which one is better to implement. Thanks.

In case of reference I am referring to this problem:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-pairs-difference-equal-k/

Comment: Better in which sense?

Comment: Ummm sorry, but your question is quite nonsensical, unless you give a measure to "better to implement". How do you define it? Also I don't think the given complexities are good.

Comment: @luk32 - Comparing the above two cases where time complexity is O(n) but space is needed to be considered and O(nLogn). Thanks!!

Comment: That's the point. How do you compare that?

Comment: With large input n. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please can someone explain which one is better to implement.

That's a design solution, and there is no clear answer for it. Each solution has its advantages and disadvantages, and choosing the "correct" one is dependent on the actual needs.

Some example considerations:

1. If your memory is very limited, or the stream of elements is very large (say it's on file of size 10GB), the hashing solution becomes infeasible, since you cannot store it in-memory, and the sorting solution + binary search becomes more attractive.
2. If you want the fastest average time possible for large arrays, and you have as much memory as you want - the hashing solution becomes more attractive due to `O(n)` average time complexity.
3. If your application runs on real time, and you cannot afford it will take `O(n^2)` time in any case, regardless how low the probability it is - it will break down your company. Since the hashing solution decays to `O(n^2)` in worst case (very rare case), you will want to avoid it, and again - sorting becomes more attractive.
4. Since both are relatively efficient, and if there is no real restrictions (which is probably 99% of the cases), the one that will be easier to implement and maintain is the one you should prefer.

Comment: Can you explain #3 a little more? Is the OP wrong in saying that the sorting solution is `O(n log n)` worst case?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior No. Sorting is strict `O(nlogn)` worst case. Hashing is `O(n)` average case, with a very rare `O(n^2)` worst case. I see your confusion - sorry for small mistake changed "sorting decays to O(n^2)" to "hashing decays to O(n^2)" - which is what I intended in the first place